# Monitor network traffic volume over interface

Tags: linux, networking, unix, monitoring, ip

Is there a way to monitor the traffic (e.g., get a live view of the utilization) over a particular network interface, say eth0?

The catch here is that the set of tools on the box is fixed, and is pretty much a stock RHEL deployment, so add-on tools can't be used.

Looking for something basic and usually present like iostat here.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596590/how-can-i-get-the-current-network-interface-throughput-statistics-on-linux-unix. Some of the suggestions on there should be useful.

Comment: D'oh, search fail (and I tried).  To be fair, I think it's a serverfault question, not a SO one :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The data you want to see shows up in good old ifconfig.

```
watch ifconfig eth0
```

or to make things stand out better:

```
watch -n 1 -d ifconfig eth0
```

Comment: Thanks - this in addition to the comment by @user239558 was just right. I'm accepting your answer since you were the first to mention `ifconfig`.

Comment: Spot on. This is something I've been looking for and although there are many similar questions to this on different forums, this is the first answer I found that nails it.

Comment: ifconfig is not in the default path. /sbin/ifconfig may be required.

Answer (score 20):

I use iftop command. It shows statistics in realtime.

```
iftop -i eth0
```

Checkout some sceenshots here:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/iftop-guide-display-network-interface-bandwidth-usage-on-linux/

Comment: Looks great, unfortunately I am not able to install any new tools on these locked down boxes.

Answer (score 7):

on post-2015 or so linux this might be better

`watch -n1 -d ip -s link show [interface]`

Comment: Best answer today. You can also use `-h[uman-readable]` with `ip`

Answer (score 4):

Without installing new tools:

`while ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX bytes'; do sleep 10; done`

Answer (score 4):

```
function humanValue()
{
    h=( '' K M G T P )
    i=1; v=$(( $1 * 8 ))
    while [ $v -gt $(( 1 << 10 * i )) ]; do let i++; done;
    echo -n "$(( $v >> 10 * --i )) ${h[i]}b/s";
}
ifaces=$(ip addr | grep -E "^[0-9]:" | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d \:)
declare -A RX2 TX2;
while sleep 1; 
do
    date 
    for INTERFACE in $ifaces;
    do
        RX1=$(cat /sys/class/net/${INTERFACE}/statistics/rx_bytes)
        TX1=$(cat /sys/class/net/${INTERFACE}/statistics/tx_bytes)
        DOWN=$(( RX1 - RX2[$INTERFACE] ))
        UP=$(( TX1 - TX2[$INTERFACE] ))
        RX2[$INTERFACE]=$RX1; TX2[$INTERFACE]=$TX1
        echo -e "[ $INTERFACE:\tRX: $(humanValue $DOWN)\t|\tTX: $(humanValue $UP) ]"
    done;
done;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of utilities:

1. Nethogs
2. iptraf
3. Iptables can be a good solution to but if you are using a
   firewall set up will be a bit hard to relocate correctly the rules

Comment: iptraf is exactly what i was looking for. But its last release seems be in IPTraf 3.0.0 - September 19, 2005. can this be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use iptables to do such think:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $port -i eth0`

and

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport $port -i eth0`

Then iptables -L -n -v will print you how many packets have been going through the interface, iptables -Z to zero this count

Comment: Output chain should have -o as interface, -i is illegal

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `ntop`. It provides a lot of detailed data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
netstat -w8 -h -i eth0
```

Which will display bits/sand in/out. `-w8` Waits 8 seconds, `-h` converts output to humand readable numbers. Works in Linux/FreeBSD.